# Computer should guess the number in my head in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a program where I have a number in my head and the computer must guess it until I say that it has guessed right!
The computer should choose a random number between 1 to 99 and show it to me, If the number is correct I should type "c" to prove that it's correct, if the number in my head is smaller I should write "s" to make the range smaller and if the number in my head was bigger I should write "b" to make the range smaller and easier for the computer to guess the number.
this is the code I came up with but there's something wrong with it that I can't find out.

```
    import random
    first=1
    second=99
    guess=random.randint(first,second)
    print(guess)
    answer=input("what is the number in your head(don't enter it, just compare it with the number on the screen)? print c for correct, b for bigger and s for smaller! \n")
    while answer!="c":
        if answer=="b":
            first==guess+1
            guess=random.randint(first,second)
            print(guess)
        elif answer=="s":
            second==guess-1
            guess=random.randint(first,second)
            print(guess)
    answer=input("what do you think about the new number? ")
    print("you did it!")
```

Comment: `first==guess+1` should be `first=guess+1`. Same for `second`

Comment: use single `=` with first and second object. and keep `answer` object at last inside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes: using `==` (testing for equality) where you should have used `=` (assignment), and wrong indentation:

```
import random
first = 1
second = 99
guess = random.randint(first, second)
print(guess)
answer = input("what is the number in your head(don't enter it, just compare it with the number on the screen)? print c for correct, b for bigger and s for smaller! \n")
while answer != "c":
    if answer == "b":
        first = guess + 1 # <-- this line
        guess = random.randint(first, second)
        print(guess)
    elif answer == "s":
        second = guess - 1 # <-- this line
        guess = random.randint(first, second)
        print(guess)
    answer = input("what do you think about the new number? ")  # <-- and this line
print("you did it!")
```

The final line would only run after the loop ended instead of once every loop the way you wrote it.

See how the spaces I added make it clearer what's going on on each line

Comment: Thank youuuuu it finally workeddd, I can't believe it was as simple as this, thank youuuuu

Answer (score 0):

You should indent the second input line so that it belongs to the while loop. This way new input is requested after every guess.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct, it just needs a few modifications in the while loop. It should look like this:

```
while answer != "c":
    if answer == "b":
       first = guess+1
       guess = random.randint(first, second)
       print(guess)
    elif answer == "s":
       second = guess-1
       guess = random.randint(first, second)
       print(guess)
    answer = input("what do you think about the new number? ")
```